How to solve, or quantify solutions of, polynomial equations in $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/\langle x^\mu - 1, y^\nu - 1\rangle$?
Suppose I was given an equation in $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$ under the identification $x^\mu = 1$ and $y^\nu = 1$ for some integers $\mu,\nu$, with some unknowns $c[x,y]$ and $d[x,y]$. For example:
\begin{equation}
(1+x)\cdot c[x,y] + (1 + xy)\cdot d[x,y] = 0
\end{equation}
How do you find solutions for $c$ and $d$ in a systematic way, and given general equations of above form, are there tools you can employ to quantify bounds on the number of solutions for example? Any hint in the right direction to tackle such problems would be much appreciated, thanks!

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ann}{Ann}$
Let $R=\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/\langle x^\mu-1,y^\nu-1\rangle$ and let $a,b\in R$. To find the number of solutions in $R$ of the linear equation
$$a\cdot c[x,y]+b\cdot d[x,y]=0,$$
we can consider the $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear map $\psi:R^2\rightarrow R$ given by $(c,d)\mapsto ac+bd$.
The set of all solutions to the above equation is $\ker(\psi)$ and the image of $\psi$ is $\langle a,b\rangle$, therefore
\begin{align*}
\lvert\ker(\psi)\rvert &= \frac{\lvert R\rvert^2}{\lvert\langle a,b\rangle\rvert}\\
&=\frac{2^{2\mu\nu}}{\lvert\langle a,b\rangle\rvert}.
\end{align*}
For the example equation in your question, $a=1+x$ and $b=1+xy$ and since $\langle 1+x,1+xy\rangle=\langle 1+x,1+y\rangle$ is the kernel of the evaluation map $x\mapsto 1$, $y\mapsto 1$, we have $\lvert\langle a,b\rangle\rvert=2^{\mu\nu-1}$. So there are $2^{\mu\nu+1}$ solutions to
$$(1+x)\cdot c[x,y]+(1+xy)\cdot d[x,y]=0.$$
To find the set of solutions, you could represent $\psi$ as a matrix and use row reduction to find a basis for the kernel.
Alternatively, there is a bijection between the set of solutions and the set
$$\left(\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle\right)\times\Ann_R(a)\times\Ann_R(b).$$
which maps a triple $(ac=bd,r_1,r_2)$ to the solution pair $(c+r_1,d+r_2)$, where $c$ and $d$ are representatives chosen in advance and $\Ann_R(u)$ is the annihilator ideal of $u\in R$. Since this is a direct product of ideals, you can represent the set of solutions using ideal generators rather than with a basis, which may be more useful in some cases.
The equation for the kernel above tells us that the number of solutions is a power of $2$ and provides the bounds
$$2^{\mu\nu}\leq\lvert\ker(\psi)\rvert\leq 2^{2\mu\nu}.$$
These bounds can be restricted in some cases, for example if $a$ and $b$ are nonzero and distinct and $\mu$ is even, then
$$\lvert\ker(\psi)\rvert\leq 2^{2\mu\nu-2}$$
is a strict upper bound, with equality for example when
\begin{align*}
a&=(1+x+x^2+\dotsb+x^{\mu-1})(1+y+y^2+\dotsb+y^{\nu-1}),\\
b&=(1+x^2+x^4+\dotsb+x^{\mu-2})(1+y+y^2+\dotsb+y^{\nu-1}).
\end{align*}
For choices of $\mu$ and $\nu$ that are not too large, the linear algebra approach should work quite well to compute the solutions / the number of solutions exactly. But without strong restrictions on $a$ and $b$, the bounds will not be very useful.
